# Basic approach for better way of single page authentication

Tags: php, jquery, css

Hey I wanted to have a page like www.example.com and it works for both public as well as authenticated users on the same front page just like facebook's front page which works nicely for public and well as their users. So my question how should I do it, I mean i can do something like this on the front page, eg.

```
<div id="user_content">...</div>

<div id="public_content">...</div>
```

and make them display 'none' or 'block' if $_SESSION[] is set or now, well in that case my potential user's content would still be visible in source code and i wanna hide it from people until they have  signed up, how should I make it work?

Any suggestions or help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If I read the source code I would see the display: none elements as well as the display: block content. You will just have to test with PHP.

Comment: I suggest using PHP to generate the HTML content conditionally based on whether a user is authenticated. You may want to do a little research and give it a try, then let us know what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: You can, but nothing's stopping an unauthenticated user from manually showing the user content.

Comment: @showdev generating dynamic HTML is much better right?

Comment: As others have mentioned here, using CSS to hide content is not secure because it happens "client-side" -- anyone can manipulate your code in their browser and view hidden content. PHPs generation of the appropriate content happens "server-side", before the user downloads anything -- so content you want to hide from them will never be downloaded. That's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would be best to have PHP show different content depending on whether they are logged in, as opposed to sending the content to the browser in both instances.

```
if($_SESSION['authenticated']){
    echo "
       This is the content an authenticated user would see.
    ";
}
else{
    echo "
       This is the content a regular visitor would see.
    ";
}
```

You just need to work on how you will authenticate users... without more information it's hard to know the best advice to give.

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if your user is logged in and if so, display different content.  Assuming your logged in user has a userid session variable it would look like this:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_SESSION['userid'] ) ) : ?>
     <div>
          <!-- user content -->
     </div>
<?php else : ?>
     <div>
          <!-- public content -->
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would not recommend using display:none; to hide user content from the public, anyone can just inspect the page to get access to protected content.

Comment: Or keep different content in different php files so its easier to manage and include() appropriate file based on the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the templated if syntax, to send different HTML based on whether or not the session is present for the user:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION[])): ?>
<html>
    ...
    <div id="loggedIn">Logged in users see this</div>
    ...
</html>
<?php else: ?>
<html>
    ...
    <div id="notLoggedIn">Not logged in users see this</div>
    ...
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This approach is processed on the server-side with PHP and avoids the problem of the HTML being visible on the client's side (using `display:none`).